# Proofing map $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^3$ is injective ?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V \subset \Bbb R^2$ be open, $h:V \to \Bbb R$ differentialable and $f: V \to \Bbb R^3$  $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y,h(x,y))$

I want to show that f is injective.

Just wanted to know what/how I can do this ? Jacobian ? Implicit function theorem ? Rank-Nullity theorem ?

Comment: It's quite obvious from the first two coordinates, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much simpler than that. If $f(a, b) = f(c, d)$, then what can you say about the first two coordinates?

Comment: OMG  - thanks ! I got it !